# issue with sanitizing HTML using "sanitize-html" npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to documentation, i tried the following code

```
const dirty = '<div>Content</div>';
const clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty);
```

The expected output of clean should be "Content", but this returns "clean" returns same value from dirty with div tags

Comment: But `<div>Content</div>` *is* valid HTML? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want strip all HTML and return only the text content of `dirty`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're intending on inserting the value back into an innerHTML possibly for modifying the statement but ensuring the user doesn't insert HTML in say your chat-box?

```js
let received_message ="<div>this should break chat boxes</div>";
let message = received_message.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');

document.querySelector("#hacked").innerHTML += received_message;
document.querySelector("#nothacked").innerHTML += message;
```

```html
<div id="hacked"></div>
<div id="nothacked"></div>
```

This will strip < and > and turn all HTML, Javascript, and other forms of injection off in your HTML if input is to be worried of like that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not specified to remove/replace the `<div>` & `</div>` tags. Failing to do so can lead to it not removing/replacing anything. According to [the documentation on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) the DIV tags are allowed by default. You'll have to manually disallow them.

Example solution:

```
const clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty, { allowedTags: [ 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ] });
```

This disables any textual tags other than those specified. You may have to replace allowedTags with allowedAttributes, in that case simply replace the tags specified with 'href' for the sake of this example.

Comment: This is not safe practice, there's too many tags and the fastest way is to just cancel tags in general. This will prevent an XSS attack on users if strict however unlikely. Unless designing a code-box to block certain HTML/Javascript I'd avoid this.

Comment: Users should avoid that of what just happened in my code-example on their sites/etc. I wrote <div></div> and it's now invisible good thing code is safe. :) Here it's stripped.

Comment: The idea of sanitize-html is that is disables anything that isn't specifically allowed. But yes, a better practice is to just remove all tags. It is important to consider there are sometimes various ways to inject code however, so OP should consider blocking all potential tags, illegal markup, or special characters that could affect the site if that is the intended application of this. My comment was about what OP asked specifically, not about a public website that needed XSS/HTML Injection filtering.

Comment: @CaseyKuilman It worked and this module just returns everything in a div , i tried passing a <h1>firstname<h1> it just returned it as a string, is it the actual behaviour of this module

Comment: @Tej yes, sanitize-html will return it as a blank string since that is not specified to be allowed.

Comment: @CaseyKuilman if i allow h1, it shows <h1>first name</h1>can you sujjest me how can i use this module if i want to show content in a h1 tag

Comment: @Tej If you allow a certain tag, say h1, it will no longer remove that tag. So in order to show content in a h1 tag, simply allow h1, and then use <h1>CONTENT</h1>.

Comment: @CaseyKuilman if i do allow h1  it just show it as a string like "<h1>content</h1>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232390/discussion-between-tej-and-casey-kuilman).

Comment: @Tej simply allow whichever tag you seek to use. A header in HTML is a part of the page (at the top). More information can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-5-header-tag/). So to use the header tag, allow header under allowedTags or allowedAttributes (I am not familiar with this specific module, so I don't know for a fact which of the two would be the one for the <header> tag.